# Differentiate composite of derivative

Tags: derivatives, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

Continuing from [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2264653/443110), let $f : S \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be *differentiable* on $S$, let $x \in S$, and consider the derivative of a composite of its derivative, evaluated at a specific point:

$$
  \frac{d}{dy}\bigg|_{y = x}\big[[f'(y) - f'(x)]^2\big]
$$

The counterexample in the answer to my previous question makes use of a function which is not the derivative of another function. With this further restriction, is the above expression defined? It seems like the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112067/443110) of the maximum degree of discontinuity of a derivative may be relevant, but I can't seem to find the answer to my specific question there.

Comment: It might be easier if you told us what you are trying to obtain, rather than struggle for yourself with it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not, for the same argument as in your previous question; in fact, this question is in no way different from the previous one if you take $F = f' : S \to \Bbb R$ and apply the previous reasoning to $F$ instead of $f$ (since it is not necessary that $F$ be differentiable).

Comment: I don't quite follow; what exactly are you choosing as $S$, $f$, and $x$ (as denoted in the question above) here?